# Увеличение ImageView при нажатии на него

Tags: java, android

Есть ImageView. Как сделать увеличение этого ImageView при нажатии на него и возвращение к стандартному размеру после повторного нажатия?

Погуглив нашел такой код. Вроде всё работает, но после повторного нажатия не возвращает первоначальный размер ImageView.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/history_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                isImageFitToScreen=false;
                button3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                button3.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            }else{
                isImageFitToScreen=true;
                button3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                button3.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Можете просто показывать это же изображение в диалоге, который будет на весь экран при клике

Comment: А PropertyAnimator пробывали делать ? он как раз изменяет scaleFactor у View элемента при sclae анимации, там две строчки кода и смотреться будет ок.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class StackRu573629 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isImageScaled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stack_ru_573629);

        ImageView img_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_1);
        img_1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isImageScaled) v.animate().scaleX(1.4f).scaleY(1.4f).setDuration(500);
            if (isImageScaled) v.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(500);
            isImageScaled = !isImageScaled;
        });
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, но что делать, если у меня изображение находится в углу экрана, а я хочу увеличить его почти на весь экран?